# How to count occurrence of words in a string dimension which contains list of strings as entries in Tableau

Tags: string, tableau-api, counting

I need to count occurrence of words in a cloumn. The column has lists of strings. E.g. of one entry in the column is: ["str1", "str2", "str3"]

I want to do this in order to graph the total numbers of each string over the whole dataset.

The length of the list is not equal for all entries of the column.

I know I can do this in Python by just looping over the column. But even if I got there, how do I integrate this into Tableu to include a graph there?

The data I have is like this:

```
 area   region     Top brands

  A1     R1        ["b1", "b3"]
  A2     R2        ["b2","b4","b5","b6"]
  A3     R4        ["b1","b4","b5","b6"]
  A4     R3        ["b1","b3","b6"]
  A4     R2        ["b7"]
```

I have two other fields which hold area and region information.

My goal is to get the top brands over the areas as well as over regions.

Comment: Clarify what you want to count. Do you just want to know the length of each list — I.e. count commas? Do you want to know how many rows contain a particular item, say b3? Maybe show an example of your desired output

Comment: Better to avoid putting multiple items in a cell, and instead to have 2 tables in third normal form that you join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found from a person on Tableau forum: [Tableau Forums](https://community.tableau.com/message/460674#460674)

Comment: The solution that worked for me is the solution from Bora Beran.